# Accessing inner controls of UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am building a custom UserControl which would allow me to place text inside a ProgressBar. The problem is, none of the ProgressBar's DependencyProperties get transferred over. Here is the XAML for my custom UserControl.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class = "MyProgram.MyCustomProgressBar"
    xmlns   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar    Name="uiProgressBar"    />
        <Label          Name="uiLabel"          />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I access and set the Minimum, Maximum, Value, etc. from XAML when I start using this UseControl.

```
<local:MyCustomProgressBar x:Name="uiLoadTime" ??.uiProgressBar.Maximum="50" />
```

I am hoping I don't need to redefine a bunch of DependencyProperties in order to get this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use a DependencyProperty... it's not so bad once you got used to it really.

Use the "propdp" built in snippet in the code-behind of your usercontrol.

Let's take the ProgressBar.Maximum example:

Make an integer dependencyproperty with a default value of 100 (or whatever you like), name it InnerProgressBarMax.

In your UserControl's XAML, you bind it this way:

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding InnerProgressBarMax, ElementName=myUsrCtrl}" />
```

When you use the control in another part of your application, simply enter a value like this:

```
<local:MyCustomProgressBar x:Name="uiLoadTime" InnerProgressBarMax="50" />
```

Rinse & repeat for each property you want to expose.

**Edit:**
If you really need to have 50+ DP exposed, you could bring down the hastle by specifying smart default values for your DPs.

To do that, when you create a DP, set the parameter of `new PropertyMetadata(YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE)`

Once that is done, your control may expose many DPs, but you'll only have to set a few manually in the XAML code that uses the control.

Comment: Yes but I really don't want to deal with redefining 50 different PropertyDependencies and dealing with their Coerce and Validation methods when I could just access them directly.

Comment: Can you please elude on the many different DP you need to expose? you might have an architectural issue. Also, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to wrapping everything in DependencyProperties is to let the UserControl's consumer provide the `ProgressBar`. It could look like this:

`<local:MyCustomProgressBar x:Name="uiLoadTime">
    <local:MyCustomProgressBar.ProgressBar>
        <ProgressBar Maximum="50" />
    </local:MyCustomProgressBar.ProgressBar>
</local:MyCustomProgressBar>`

Then in `MyCustomProgressBar.xaml.cs`, you would expose a public property for a ProgressBar. In its setter, modify the properties however you see fit, then add it to the UserControl's root `Grid`.